# How to access the Outbound SMTP Server address from code?

Tags: 2010, email

I am currently working on sending an email with an iCal event that users can accept/decline to add it to their calendar.  The built-in `SPUtility.SendEmail` is too limited to achieve this so I'm using `SmtpClient` instead.  However, I've needed to hard code the Outbound SMTP Server shown in the image below because I've been unable to find this property from the SharePoint API:

[image: Outbound SMTP Server]

This is obviously going to cause problems when the Outbound SMTP server changes because I will have to remember to update it in 2 places.  How can I access this property using the SharePoint API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [an article by Randy Drisgill](http://blog.drisgill.com/2007/05/programmatically-using-outgoing-smtp.html) that describes how to get the SMTP server by using the `SPWebApplication`.

The one-line code to get the property is `SPContext.Current.Web.Site.WebApplication.OutboundMailServiceInstance.Server.Address`.

Answer (score -3):

Look at this article. Should help:

http://manasbhardwaj.net/how-to-send-email-using-sharepoint/

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines. Also we  require disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.